# GCP API Gateway Open API definition, can it be partial?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, reverse-proxy, google-cloud-run

API Gateway in GCP requires an Open API definition. It looks like this definition must be very precise (includes all HTTP methods and all endpoints). Ex:

```
paths:
  /v1/hello:
    get:
      summary: Hi Service
      operationId: hello-v1
      x-google-backend:
        address: <CLOUD_RUN_URL>
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
```

Is there something in the spec to define only partial definitions? End goal would be to use API Gateway as a kind of reverse proxy.

Example:

anything behind `/path1` goes to `Cloud Run URL 1`,

anything behind `/path2` goes to `Cloud Run URL 2`.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to create this figure

[image]

and by adding the relavant `path-rules` you can accomplish what you described

```
gcloud compute url-maps add-path-matcher api-gateway-url-map \
    --path-matcher-name=my-pm2  \
    --default-service=my-host-default-backend \
    --path-rules="/video=video-service,/video/*=video-service" \
    --new-hosts my-hosts.com
```

See the full documentation page for: [Getting started with HTTP(S) Load Balancing for API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/gateway-serverless-neg)

Comment: Doing so, I would still have to configure an Open API schema into the API Gateway part of that process, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a wildcard and path_translation

```
/v1/hello/{another_path=**}:
    get:
      summary: Hi Service
      operationId: hello-v1
      x-google-backend:
        address: <CLOUD_RUN_URL>
        path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
```

That means that the path <API_GATEWAY_URL>/v1/hello/world/123 will be forwarded to <CLOUD_RUN_URL>/v1/hello/world/123